# How to extend the existing login process

Tags: login

Using `Sitecore 10.1.2`

I would like to log the CMS user information like username, email, and logged-in timestamp as soon as a user logs into the CMS.

The details would be captured in a custom table with some business logic.

We have both native CMS & Azure AD accounts.

Could you please suggest the method, processor or pipeline where I can add my custom logic?

**Update:**

Following the suggestion, I have implemented this.

These are the existing settings from `ShowConfig.aspx`.

[image]

**My patch config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <processors>
        <loggedin argsType="Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggedIn.LoggedInArgs">
          <processor mode="on" type="MyProject.Foundation.Accounts.CMS.CmsLoginAudit.SaveAuditLog, MyProject.Foundation.Accounts" resolve="true"/>
        </loggedin>
      </processors>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**And the class:**

```
namespace MyProject.Foundation.Accounts.CMS
{
    public class CmsLoginAudit
    {
        public void SaveAuditLog()
        {
            if (Context.IsLoggedIn)
            {
                User user = Context.User;
                MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(user.Name);
                var userId = membershipUser?.ProviderUserKey;
                var userIp = GetUserIpAddress();
                string userEmail = membershipUser.Email;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `ShowConfig.aspx` does include the the patch config settings.

[image]

But the debugger isn't hitting the `SaveAuditLog` method.
What am I missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling my class like this, worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
        <processor  patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.CreateTicket, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']"
            type="MyProject.Foundation.Accounts.CMS.CmsLoginAudit.SaveAuditLog, MyProject.Foundation.Accounts" resolve="true"/>
      </owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a processor in the `loggedin` pipeline. This should be executed after each login.

```
<processors>
   <loggedin>
     <processor mode="on" type="...." resolve="true"/>
   </loggedin>
</processors>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `SaveAuditLog` method is not triggered due to the pipeline/processor execution order. If you check with /showconfig.aspx, `<owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>` pipeline related processor gets executed as by default identity server is enabled.

You can disable the identity server if not using  `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Disabler.config.example` from \App_Config\Include\Examples\ Rename the file to .config

Also, update the class to use `LoggedInProcessor`.

```
 public class CmsLoginAudit : LoggedInProcessor
    {
        private readonly BaseAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
        public BaseLog Log { get; }


        public CmsLoginAudit(BaseAuthenticationManager authenticationManager, BaseLog log)
        {
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
            Log = log;
        }

        public override void Process(LoggedInArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User activeUser = authenticationManager.GetActiveUser();
            Log.Info(string.Format("Email {0} UserName {1} LoggedInTime {2}", activeUser.Profile.Email, activeUser.Profile.UserName, Sitecore.DateUtil.ToIsoDate(System.DateTime.Now)), this);
        }
    }
```

I'm just trying to log the info here and the result looks like this:

`30576 18:17:44 INFO  Email testuser@test.com UserName sitecore\TestUser LoggedInTime 20230116T1817441`

patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <processors>
            <loggedin>
                <processor patch:before="processor[position()=last()]" method="Process"  mode="on" type="ExploreSitecore.Feature.Test.CmsLoginAudit, ExploreSitecore.Feature.Test" resolve="true"/>
            </loggedin>
        </processors>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

If you are using the identity server then `<owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>` works fine.

Comment: Sorry, could be a dumb question but how do I decide whether to enable or disable identityserver. We have logins from AzureAD as well. Also, isn't identityserver a default for native CMS login?

Comment: Sitecore Identity (SI) is a mechanism to log in to Sitecore. It was introduced in Sitecore 9.1. It builds on the Federated Authentication functionality introduced in Sitecore 9.0 and the Sitecore Identity server, which is based on IdentityServer4. It provides a separate identity provider and allows you to set up SSO (Single Sign-On) across Sitecore services and applications.

If you are not using any sso/federated authentication, you can disable it. Yes, Sitecore 9.1.0 and later enabled the Sitecore Identity by default.